# Know when view presented using addAndSetupAccessoriesWithCompletionHandler

Tags: ios, objective-c, homekit, ios-homekit

From iOS 10 onwards apple have introduced the `addAndSetupAccessoriesWithCompletionHandler` method to add the `HMAccessories` to the home. In this method `^(NSError *error` block is executing when we successfully add/cancel the accessory setup.

But my question is I would like to know when this viewController is presented? For reference I have attached the image. Thank you so much for your valuable time. Any ideas/suggestions will be appreciate.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't look like there is an easy way to do this using public API. This view controller is created out-of-process and communicated to through a proxy. You *may* be able to figure out when presentation happens by swizzling `_presentAsTopmostViewController`, but I wouldn't recommend it. What are you trying to do that you need this information for?

Comment: @SaagarJha based on this I want to change the status bar color

Comment: Yeah, I don't think you can do that, since it's not in your process. It *might* pickup something you put into `UIAppearance`, but that's not a guarantee.

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look first on [HomeKitDeveloperGuide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/HomeKitDeveloperGuide/WritingtotheHomeKitDatabase/WritingtotheHomeKitDatabase.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015050-CH4-SW1), do you may use a [trigger](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/homekit/hmhome/1620271-addtrigger) ?

Comment: @A STEFANI triggers are different than add accessory. I am asking about the accessorysetup viewController. According to me there is no interconnectivity between trigger and accessory.